# Android: how to add a view and immediately triger onTouch without it really being touched

Tags: java, android, view, ontouch

I'm trying to do the following:

1) adding a view to a layout when long-clicking the layout

2) while the finger is still on the screen triggering onTouch for the added view as if you pulled up      your finger and touched the view after it has been added

(this is used for adding a view and dragging it without the need to touch twice)

Comment: You can create a method that will contain all the code from onTouch listener and call this method after the insertion of the view.

Comment: I need the MotionEvent from the onTouch in order to preform the dragging